# Can you Count() your assets? (windows 8 store app)

Tags: c#, windows-8

I am working on recreating the game Memory for Windows 8.
One of my goals is to allow a user to add images of their own.
It'd be useful if I could keep track of how many images there are.

Currently I am attempting to Count() the amount of images I have in my Assets folder, this way I can decide whether to use an image set more than once or if I can stick with having unique sets.

Does anybody know of a way to do this?
Or, even better, an easier or more efficient way to do so?

OS: Windows 8.1
Program: Visual studio 2013 express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do Like this

```
        //To Access Folder
        var InstalledFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        //Get the Images Folder
        InstalledFolder = await InstalledFolder.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
        //Get files
        var files = await InstalledFolder.GetFilesAsync(); 
        var count = files.Count;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query your assets folder with the following code:

```
var folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync(); 
var count = files.Count;
```

The files must be compiled as "Content".

Comment: I found Sajeetharan's answer to be a bit better seeing as I can count subfolders separately, your answer'd more useful if I wanted to count everything.